# "must implement inherited abstract method"

Tags: java

I had this original parent abstract class Geometric and i was extending it in Octagon, and also implementing Comparable and Cloneable. IDK why i keep getting the above error.Help with be appreciated.

```
class Octagon extends GeometricObject implements Cloneable, Comparable{
  private double side;
  public class Octagon(){
  }
  public class Octagon(double s){
    side=s;
  }
  public double getArea(){
    return (2+4/Math.sqrt(2))*side*side;
  }
  public double getPerimeter(){
    return 8*side;
  }
  public int compareTo(Object o){
    if (getArea()>((Octagon)o).getArea()){
      return 1;
    }
    else if (getArea()<((Octagon)o).getArea()){
      return -1;
    }
    else 
      return 0;
  }
  public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    super.clone();
  }
}
```

And this is my Geometric Class

```
public abstract class GeometricObject{
  private String color="white";
  private boolean filled;
  private java.util.Date dateCreated;

  protected GeometricObject(){
    dateCreated=new java.util.Date();
  }

  protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled){
    dateCreated=new java.util.Date();
    this.color=color;
    this.filled=filled;
  }

  public String getColor(){
    return color;
  }
  public void setColor(String color){
    this.color=color;
  }
  public boolean isFilled(){
    return filled;
  }
  public void setFilled(boolean filled){
    this.filled=filled;
  }
  public java.util.Date getDateCreated(){
    return dateCreated;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "created on "+dateCreated+"\ncolor: "+color;
  }
  public abstract double getArea();
  public abstract double getPerimeter();
}
```

Comment: Most probably, you forgot to implement one of the abstract methods in your super class `GeometricObject`.

Comment: Sounds like maybe there's some abstract method in `GeometricObject` that you aren't overriding. The compiler should tell you exactly which method you are missing, which should answer your question.

Comment: unless you post the code of that abstract class, we can't tell you why the error occurs.

Comment: show the code of GeometricObject.

Comment: It is better to use a good IDE (eclipse/intellij/netbeans).. and you may avoid some trivial errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it - the error is within you "constructors":

```
public class Octagon(){
//     ^^^^^ <- remove
}

public class Octagon(double s){
//     ^^^^^ <- remove
  side=s;
}
```

The `class` "modifiers" are illegal. Simply remove them.

---

Bonus advice - consider changing the implementation of `compareTo`. You're looking at the octagons area, which is perfectly OK for comparision. But it requires calculating the area each and every time when two octagons need to be compared.

As the area only depends on the `side` value, it's sufficient and much more efficient to compare octagons by their `side` length:

```
public int compareTo(Object other) {

 if (!(other instanceof Octagon)) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Comparision with other types is not supported");
 }

 Integer thisSide = side;    // autoboxing, legal conversion since Java 1.5
 Integer otherSide = ((Octagon) other).side;     

 // Easy trick: Integer is already comparable ;)
 return thisSide.compareTo(otherSide);
}
```

Comment: Interesting - eclipse reports that error while javac (1.6 and 1.7) just complains about some missing `{` and `}` at the line with the illegal `class` "modifier"...

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that GeometricObject is an abstract class.  It probably has some abstract methods that need to be implemented in Octogon.

**UPDATE**:

Found it.  I pasted these two classes into Eclipse, and boom:

```
public class Octagon(){
}
public class Octagon(double s){
    side=s;
}
```

Subtle and tricky typo.  Remove the word "class" from those two constructor declarations, and you'll still have an error or two, but they should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

When you write "Octagon extends GeometricObject", you are essentially promising that your class can do everything that a GeometricObject can do, and maybe more. So if you're not implementing a method that is part of a GeometricObject, then you're breaking this promise, and the Java compiler objects to this.

Comment: if the comments on the question interpreted your confusion correctly, then my answer is somewhat unnecessary...

Comment: Oh, there wwas actually only two abstract methods in Geometric object which are getArea() and getPerimeter(). and compiler is saying i have to implement thosse, which i think i did.

Answer (score 0):

`GeometricObject` is an abstract class, and there is an `abstract` method in the cass `GeometricObject` (or one of it's super-classes) that you have not provided an implementation.

As a concrete Class cannot be constructed if one of it's abstract methods lacks an implementation, you get the compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should post the contents of `GeometricObject.java` for a definitive answer.

Nevertheless, I have a pretty good idea that it is `Comparable`.  It is properly `Comparable<T>` but you have `Comparable` in your code.  Try changing your code to `class Octagon extends GeometricObject implements Cloneable, Comparable<Object>`